# React - Dynamic AJAX loading HTML data not working in dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am not able to dynamically AJAX loaded HTML format data(as mentioned below) in `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`(ie., it is setting in DOM as the same string and not compiling). Please note that I am using `axios` plugin for AJAX API calls. When I try with the same HTML data giving statically in `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, it is working perfectly. I don't know what is going there.

```
[{id: 1, image: "assets/img/news-sm.png", content: "&lt;p&gt;சிறுவனே!&lt;/p&gt;"}]
```

My React Component code is

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import List from 'material-ui/List/List';
import ListItem from 'material-ui/List/ListItem';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';
import { Media } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { map } from 'lodash';

class NewsList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    handleListClick(d){
        console.log(d);
    }

    renderLoadingComponent() {
        return <ListItem style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Loading...</ListItem>;
    }

    renderNothingFoundElement() {
        return <ListItem style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Nothing found</ListItem>;
    }

    render() {
        const { data, loading } = this.props;

        return (
            <List className="list">
                {
                    map(data, (d, index) =>
                        React.Children.toArray([
                            <ListItem className="list-item">
                                <Media onClick={(ev) => this.handleListClick(d)} className="media-align">
                                    <Media.Left align="middle">
                                        <img width={75} height={56} src={d.image} alt="news-image"/>
                                    </Media.Left>
                                    <Media.Body>
                                        {d.content && <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: d.content }}></p>}
                                    </Media.Body>
                                </Media>
                            </ListItem>,
                            (index + 1) !== data.length ? <Divider /> : ''
                        ])
                    )
                }

                { loading ? this.renderLoadingComponent() : data.length === 0 ? this.renderNothingFoundElement() : '' }
            </List>
        )
    }
}

NewsList.propTypes = {
    data: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default NewsList;
```

I am calling the above Component from another Component like this

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import NewsList from '../components/news-list';

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { ajaxData: [], ajaxLoading: false }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/ajaxUrl')
            .then(response => this.setState({ajaxData: response.data}))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <NewsList data={this.state.ajaxData} loading={this.state.ajaxLoading} />
        )
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Not enough code. Please show the whole component, including the code that fetches data.

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin Hi. I have edited the post. Can you please look into this and let me know if I should add more?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to specify The Component Lifecycle shouldComponentUpdate or forceUpdate or componentWillReceiveProps [facebook.github.io](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html)

But you can also use a huck and set state in your Parent component to '' and on a callback set the NewList and pass props

```
this.setState({newList: ''},()=> this.setState({ newList: <NewList {...props}/>}))
```

**Update** The simple one

```
class Home extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { ajaxData: [], ajaxLoading: false, newsList:'' }
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/ajaxUrl')
        .then(response => this.setState({ajaxData: response.data},
()=> this.setState({newsList: <NewsList data={this.state.ajaxData} loading={this.state.ajaxLoading} />})))
 }

render() {
    return (
        <div> {this.state.newsList} <div/>
    )
}}
```

Also you can implement method for a life cycle

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.state.ajaxData != nextState.ajaxData;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just updated the entire post with full code. Can you give me more detailed code of your answer?

Comment: @AbrahamGnanasingh try this one

Comment: Tried it. Still the same string not compiling. When I also add `shouldComponentUpdate` code, it stopped rendering. Please note that through Network in Inspect Element, my response is actually like this `[{id: 1, image: "assets/img/news-sm.png", content: "&lt;p&gt;சிறுவனே!&lt;/p&gt;"}]`. Sorry about that.

Comment: @AbrahamGnanasingh did you try to put some different content into <NewList/>?

Comment: try also this for the NewsList `componentDidUpdate(prevProp, prevState){
    this.refs.news.innerHTML = this.props.ajaxData.content;
  }` and `<Media.Body><div ref='news'/></Media.Body>`

Comment: I tried with putting static content (&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;First &middot; Second). This works fine. But when I including tags (&lt;p&gt; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;First &middot; Second &lt;/p&gt;), this is not working. I think the issue is with reading less than or greater than entities. Is there any way to read those? FYI, I tried with `this.refs.news.innerHTML` and is not working.

Comment: `<p> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;First &middot; Second </p>`. This content is rendering perfectly. Therefore, the problem is reading with less than or greater than entities. Please see this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7825) to refer problem/screenshot of the same wrong output coming for me(In there, it's rendering html content to just string. For me, the same problem is happening when rendering with dynamic props and also it's rendering html content with entities to just string). I am using React 15.4.2